# Chief Editor has no permission to load all target list out by Core service

Tags: web8, a4t, permissions

Chief Editor can publish item to different target at CMS portal. But inside our Alchemy4Tridion plugin, when call Tridion core service to load the target list based on current user permission, it will return nothing. If we change the permission to Administrator, then it can work.

```
List<TargetTypeData> targets = new List<TargetTypeData>();
var readoptions = new ReadOptions();
var filter = new TargetTypesFilterData();
var allPublicationTargets = client.GetSystemWideList(filter);
foreach (TargetTypeData pubTarget in allPublicationTargets)
{   
    targets.Add(pubTarget);
}
return targets;
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Publishing to a target is a different permission from actually *loading* those objects, as you are doing in your code. I am sure you could send something to publish to those targets using code - because that's controlled by the same permissions that control the UI.

To load the objects you need Admin rights indeed. You could use privilege elevation (available in Web 8) to allow this code to proceed.

In Core Service, use `client.ElevatePrivileges(Privileges.ReadOnly)` to perform this action (assuming read only is enough).

EDIT

Looking through the code [here](https://github.com/Alchemy4Tridion/Alchemy4Tridion/blob/master/Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins/Clients/AlchemySessionAwareCoreServiceClient.cs) it seems that `AlchemySessionAwareCoreServiceClient` inherits directly from Tridion's `SessionAwareCoreServiceClient` - so this method should be available. Two things are possible:

1. The Alchemy client you're using is still based on the 7.1 (2013 SP1) Core Service client or
2. The method was changed between 8.1 and 8.5 (because I tested it on 8.5)

I strongly doubt #2, so my bet is on #1.

EDIT 2:

How are you instantiating your `AlchemySessionAwareCoreServiceClient`? You can tell it to use a Web 8 endpoint, see https://github.com/Alchemy4Tridion/Alchemy4Tridion/blob/master/Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins/Clients/AlchemySessionAwareCoreServiceClient.cs#L78

Comment: The AlchemySessionAwareCoreServiceClient class seems doesn't contain this method. Does it provide any other way to support this action?

Comment: See my 2 edits.

Comment: You are right about Edit one, I still use version 7.1. As a first step, I will load 8.5 to see. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Any idea where we can find Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client version 8.5?

Comment: Program files (x86)\sdl web\bin\client\coreservice